# How to manage a number of different lambdas in aws?

Tags: aws-lambda

I understand that one would quickly move to uploading files over using the UI to edit lambdas.

However, how do you *organize* aws lambdas themselves?

The UI does not show or support any directories, groups or other mechanism.
I can and do use tags but unfortunately these are not available columns in the UI lambda view that lists the various lambdas
Different developers use different approaches to tags and names and this can quickly become chaotic.

Similarly, what approaches help with to use a code review system, e.g. PRs with github gitflow, when the end result then has to be uploaded into aws lambda which also has a version management approach ($latest etc), environment stages, etc. ?

Is there a good way to automate this as a manual process is error-prone.  Maybe some sort of hook from PR merge to post new aws version but that is a fair bit of wiring perhaps

I'd like to create thousands of small methods but without soe sort of encapsulation I am not sure how to proceed, seeking advice from others what approaches you are using.

Comment: Have you checked the serverless framework out? I was in a little of lambda hell like you and that helped me. Serverless: https://serverless.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be relying on the AWS web console for production AWS Lambda management. Especially if you have a lot of Lambda functions. You should probably be using something like the AWS [Serverless Application Model](https://aws.amazon.com/serverless/sam/) (SAM), or the [Serverless framework](https://serverless.com/), or use [CloudFormation](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/) or [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/) templates to manage your functions.

You might also looking into using a continuous integration pipeline that automatically builds, tests and deploys your Lambda functions when new code is committed to a Git repository. There are many possible tools you could use to implement such a pipeline, like [CircleCI](https://circleci.com/), [Concourse](https://concourse-ci.org/), and AWS [CodePipeline](https://aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/)/[CodeBuild](https://aws.amazon.com/codebuild/)/[CodeDeploy](https://aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/).

The key is here is that the Lambda functions are part of your larger application infrastructure, and should be managed and deployed together with all other inter-related services. If API Gateway and SQS and DynamoDB all need to be updated or provisioned along with an AWS Lambda function deployment, then all of that should be managed by one tool that performs all the necessary steps. If you are doing this, then things like Lambda's internal versioning IDs are something only your deployment tool needs to care about.

> Similarly, what approaches help with to use a code review system, e.g.
>   PRs with github gitflow, when the end result then has to be uploaded
>   into aws lambda which also has a version management approach ($latest
>   etc), environment stages, etc. ?

I fail to see how Lambda version IDs are directly related to Git PRs. Your PRs happen in Git, so use Git to manage code reviews.